# Can't connect to ServerSocket using global IP address

Tags: java, sockets, portforwarding

I'm creating a ServerSocket on my local computer:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8999);
System.out.println("Listening");
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
```

When I connect to it using:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8999);
```

it works perfectly. But when I instead try to connect to it using my global IP address (also tested from a different IP then the one the server is using):

```
Socket socket = new Socket("*correct global ip placed here*", 8999);
```

I get a timeout. I have forward port 8999/TCP in the firewall to my computer. Forwarding has been tested for other applications and works for them?

I tried using serverSocket.bind() with global IP and Port instead but was unable to bind to this address. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: what is the exception when you tried to bind with global ip?

Comment: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind

Comment: that means other process may be running. can you check netstat -a -n  output for your port?

Comment: By global ip address you mean an ip that your computer actually has on one interface (`ipconfig` on windows in the commandline window)? Binding to external ips of a router wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok, I'm now running the application on a server and it is working fine, I think there is a mysterious problem with my router. I'm gonna continue searching.

Comment: It's getting more mysterious. I'm unable to connect from my smartphone to a server running on my PC, both connected to the same local network. They are able to ping each other.

Comment: Is there some firewall running on the server?

Comment: The server on my PC is running on Windows. I port forwarded my router (is working for other applications) and double checked the Windows Firewall. On the external server, there is a firewall (ufw) but it's port forwarded, too. I've now worked around it by developing using the hostednetwork of Windows.